# Multi BlocBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I am a beginner in flutter and is there any examples or documentations which related to multi blocbuilder in one page by using flutter_bloc package in Flutter.

Comment: I prefer using bloc_pattern with rxdart and streambuilder. So I can have as many blocs as I want in my UI doing something like this: "final bloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<CounterBloc>();"... Maybe you could read about it to see which one you like most: https://pub.dev/packages/bloc_pattern

Comment: @Stel In bloc_pattern is hard to understand the code so that's why i prefer flutter_bloc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The latest flutter_bloc [docs](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=contextwatch) explain how to create a MultiBlocBuilder, when your Widget's builder relies on multiple BLOC's:

```
Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    final stateA = context.watch<BlocA>().state;
    final stateB = context.watch<BlocB>().state;
    final stateC = context.watch<BlocC>().state;

    // return a Widget which depends on the state of BlocA, BlocB, and BlocC
  }
);
```

The `flutter_multi_bloc_builder` somewhat simplifies this syntax (... does it?), its latest [doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_multi_bloc_builder/latest/index.html) also describes how to do the same thing using that package:

```
final bloc1 = BlocProvider.of<MyBloc1>(context);
final bloc2 = BlocProvider.of<MyBloc2>(context);
final bloc3 = BlocProvider.of<MyBloc2>(context);

MultiBlocBuilder(
    blocs: [bloc1, bloc2, bloc3],
    builder: (context, states) {
        final state1 = states.get<MyBloc1State>();
        final state2 = states.get<MyBloc2State>();
        final state3 = states.get<MyBloc3State>();
        
        if (state1 is Loading || state2 is Loading || state3 is Loading) {
            return Text("Loading");
        } else {
            return Text("SHow some content");
        }
    }
);
```

Might have been more useful if some `buildWhen` or `selector` equivalent had been offered in this package?

I hope this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

`BlocBuilder()`, like any other Widgets, can be used multiple times. To use multiple of BlocBuilders in a screen, you just need to provide the needed Streamable (Bloc) on different [BlocBuilder](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocBuilder-class.html).